# What way can be used to discover discrepancies in a PDO query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have the following

- A multidimensional array encoded as JSON. Each index holds exactly 80 keys
- A CSV file with 80 items representing identical keys in the indexes above since dumping them in the same script will be too cumbersome

First, I mutate the original keys in the JSON array to use underscores since named placeholders don't accept that

```
foreach ($content as $key => &$bulk) {

    $vals = array_values($bulk);

    $keys = array_map(function ($item) {

    $item = str_replace(' ', '_', $item);

    return ":$item"; // semi-colons are redundant but I tried it also to be on the safe side

    }, array_keys($bulk));

    $bulk = array_combine($keys, $vals);

    // add date to each fixture
    $bulk[':date'] = date('Y-m-d');
}
```

Then I do the exact same thing for items in the CSV file and convert them to what can be used in the actual query

```
// swap out spaces
array_walk($validColumns, function (&$val) {

    $val = str_replace(' ', '_', $val);
});

// prepare named placeholders
$transform = array_map(function ($val) {

    return ":$val";
}, $validColumns);

$placeholders = implode(',', $transform);

$validColumns = array_map(function ($val) {

    return "`$val`";
}, $validColumns);
```

After this, I build the query using the following string

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO container (' . implode(',', $validColumns) . ") VALUES ($placeholders)";
```

And attempt to execute with this

```
try {

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $conn->beginTransaction();

    $transaction = $conn->prepare($query);

    foreach ($content as $key => $bulk) {

        if (!is_array($bulk)) $bulk = [$bulk];

        var_dump(array_diff($transform, array_keys($bulk))); // this returns an empty array even when I swap the arguments

        $transaction->execute($bulk);
    }
```

But it keeps throwing the dreaded error `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'`. My question is how may I know what keys I'm missing, from the nested `array_diff` in the `foreach`?

When I `var_dump` the lengths, they both return 80. Same with the placeholder values. I have also tried using the object keys without adding the semi-colon but the issue persists.

Are there any additional tools I can use to detect why it relentlessly throws the error as per what the inconsistency is--whether it can't find a matching placeholder or if there are more `values` than placeholders?
I have scoured every single SO thread with this error down to the 16th search result and every time, someone posts his query and bound parameters but in my case where I have 80 length arrays and 80 length cryptic compound-word strings representing keys, that will be an effective way to deter anyone from trying to help.

Comment: Have you put `error_log($query)` into your code, and examined the error log to see exactly *what* is in the query that's being used?

Comment: Have you tried ```echo```ing the $query to see what the SQL looks like?

Comment: @SloanThrasher yes I have. It's a string of all both the keys and the placeholders. Looks like this INSERT INTO container (`key1`, `key2`, `etc`) VALUES (:key1, :key2, :etc). But since they are so many, the only sure way of comparing is getting the difference using array_compare. @FKEinternet I just error_logged and there's no message there. I also observed some keys have brackets like so key=`form_table_(last_8)1`, placeholder=:form_table_(last_8)1. Could that have any effect? Is there a way to escape those?